# Conditional KL Divergence in Clustering Paper

Tags: clustering, conditional-probability, kullback-leibler

I am trying to implement the following paper on Self-taught Clustering https://www.cse.ust.hk/~qyang/Docs/2008/dwyakicml.pdf.

I have the following three co-clustering functions:

[image: co-cluster functions]

where p̃(Z|x̃) is Z (the common feature space between data X and Z) given a cluster x̃. My goal is to minimize this function. When I expanded out the with a definition of KL divergence on probabilities I got

$D\dfrac{p(z,x)}{p(x)} || \dfrac{p(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{z})p(z)}{p(\widetilde{x})p(\widetilde{z})} = \dfrac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}log\dfrac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}*\dfrac{p(\widetilde{x})p(\widetilde{z})}{p(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{z})p(z)}$

My problem however is that **I don't have the joint probabilities of the clusters $p(\widetilde{x},\widetilde{z})$ since those are the clusters I am calculating.**

There is very little information in this paper, so if someone could advise me, that would be great! Thanks!